# WebSphere MQ on Remote Machine

Tags: ibm-mq

I have been using WebSphere MQ lately to send message from local machine to the WebSphere MQ present on same (local) machine. Which works fine as expected.

I dont know how to install WebSphere MQ in other/remote Machine so that I can send message form my local machine to that remote machine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this but the most likely is that you will need to install an Websphere MQ Client onto the remote machine. I am not sure what version you want to use but the WMQ 7.5 client is available here [MQC75](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744) You can google for other versions by changing the number (MQC7, MQC71, MQC8 etc).

You haven't said what language your application is written in, if it is Java then the WMQ Client provides everything you need, if it is C/C++ or .NET then the page I linked to has more information about what you need for these languages.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I am using WMQ 8.0. Java is the language I have used to connect. I have installed WebSphere MQ explorer on my local machine. client should be installed seperately  with WMQ explorer? What are the different ways it can be installed in remote machine? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes the WMQ Client and WMQ Explorer are seperate installs. WMQ Explorer allows you to administrator either a local or remote queue manager(s). The WMQ client allows you to run applications connecting to remote queue managers.

Comment: Forgot to add: You install the WMQ Client on the remote box and then reference the <WMQClientInstall>/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar if you are using v8. If you are running you app in an application server then you need to use the WMQ JCA Resoource Adapter (in the <WMQClientInstall>/lib/jca directory) and deploy it into the app server (unless you are using WAS in which case you already have it, although not a v8 WMQ RA).

Comment: Hi, I have installed WMQ client 8.0. After installation it creates a folder in Start containing options including "Launch WebSphere MQ explorer" . I am not able to understand what is client here as explorer was already installed on my machine. Please help how to use it

Comment: The question would be how "How are you sending messages to WebSphere MQ?" i.e. Do you have an application to do it or some code? WMQ Explorer is a GUI application that allows you to administer a queue manager. An WMQ Client is not a GUI application but a set of libraries and function to communicate to a remote queue manager.

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot again! that's what my understanding was. Client is set of libraries but when you told to install it I got confused. I am using java application to send message which has all the required IBM jars. But its sending message to my WebSphere MQ running on local machine using host as "localhost" but I want to send message from where client is located in different machine. In this case it will not send to message to localhost. So main question was how to setup WebSphere MQ so that I can send message to it from client located anywhere  apart from localhost.

Comment: You just change the host in your java code from 'localhost' to either the host name or ip address of the remote queue manager you want to connect to.

Comment: If you need more info then a copy of the java code you already have to connect will help.

Comment: I dont know how to run WebSPhere MQ in remote host because when we install by default it runs on localhost.

Comment: I am not sure you mean by 'runs on local host'. Whether you connect locally or remotely should have nothing to do with how you start the mq server.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not providing details, when I say localhost it means its running on host 127.0.0.1 which can not be accessed by outside world. So I am not able to connect it with from other machine. Hope you are understanding my problem and can provide me with the solution. Thanks for your continuous response.

Comment: Assuming that machine has a network card then you will need to find out the real IP address or host name. Run either ipconfig or ifconfig on the remote machine to did that information out. All machines have localhost (127.0.0.1) configured.

Comment: Yes every machine has localhost , but how to connect this machine from other machine as WMQ automatically uses localhost when we install it. Is there a way where we can specify the host on which WMQ should run?

Comment: You said "WMQ automatically uses localhost when we install it." but it doesn't. On the WMQ QueueManager you should have a listener that is bound to a port (1414 probably). You can access that listener from your java application either using localhost(1414) (if you are local) or <actual_host/ip_address>(1414) if you are remote to the queue manager. There is no need to change anything on the QueueManager side.